How can I configure Google Cloud Run and sharp so that my generated images contain text instead of boxes?
I've built a service using Node.js & sharp that composites some text onto a background image:
exports.social_get_result = async function(req,res,next){
    // Path to the existing background image
    const backgroundImagePath = './static/images/bg/social-'+ req.params.division.replace(/([\s]{1,})/g,'-') +'.png';

    // Text settings
    const linesOfText = ["Result: "+ req.params.homeTeam +" vs ", req.params.awayTeam,req.params.homeScore +"-"+ req.params.awayScore,"#tameside #badminton #tbl #result","https://tameside-badminton.co.uk"];
    const textSize = 60;
    const textColor = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 1 }; // White color
    const lineHeight = 1.2; // Line height multiplier
    const image = sharp(backgroundImagePath);

    // Get the metadata of the image (e.g., dimensions)
    const metadata = await image.metadata();
    const width = metadata.width;
    const height = metadata.height;

    // Create an SVG overlay with multiple lines of text
   
    const svgText = `
        <svg width="${width}" height="${height}">
        <style>
            .title { fill: rgba(${textColor.r}, ${textColor.g}, ${textColor.b}, ${textColor.alpha}); font-size: ${textSize}px; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial }
            .footer { fill: rgba(${textColor.r}, ${textColor.g}, ${textColor.b}, ${textColor.alpha}); font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial }
        </style>
            <text x="10%" y="70%" text-anchor="left">
                <tspan x="10%" dy="1.2em" class="title">${linesOfText[0]}</tspan>
                <tspan x="10%" dy="1.2em" class="title">${linesOfText[1]}</tspan>
                <tspan x="10%" dy="1.2em" class="title">${linesOfText[2]}</tspan>
                <tspan x="10%" dy="1.2em" class="footer">${linesOfText[3]}</tspan>
                <tspan x="10%" dy="1.2em" class="footer">${linesOfText[4]}</tspan>
            </text>
        </svg>`;

    const buffer = Buffer.from(svgText);

    // Composite the text onto the existing image
    const finalImage = await image
        .composite([{ input: buffer }])
        .toFormat('JPG')
        .toFile('static/images/generated/'+ req.params.homeTeam.replace(/([\s]{1,})/g,'-') + req.params.awayTeam.replace(/([\s]{1,})/g,'-') +'.jpg')
    
    const outputImage = await image
    .composite([{ input: buffer }])
    .toBuffer()
    .then(data => res.type('png').send(data))
  }

Currently, once deployed on Google Cloud Run, this outputs:

whereas locally I get:

Logs show an error of:
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)

I've already attempted a number of options:

different fonts in the svg (Arial, sans-serif, dejavu, "DejaVu Sans")
put an Arial.ttf (and fonts.conf) in multiple places (root of the service, in a fonts folder, in a 'rootfiles' folder that (i.e. so that it's available at https://tameside-badminton.co.uk/Arial.ttf, in the 'home' folder via the cloudshell console)
passed FC_DEBUG values (1 etc.) and simpl
passed FONTCONFIG_PATH and FONTCONFIG_FILE values like /usr/share/fonts, /fonts, ~/fonts/
set PANGOCAIRO_BACKEND = fontconfig
ran fc-list, fc-cat, fc-cache that show fonts like Dejavu Sans etc. etc.

I understand that serverless environments need some level of config, but I can't seem to get it to either find the font files that are available, or the fonts.conf file, which I understand (from reading through the sharp docs, and the fontconfig docs, as well as many other posts about similar challenges with AWS Lambda solutions) are required for serverless environments.
I can't help thinking that the (null) part of the default configuration error is trying to tell me something, but beyond FONTCONFIG_PATH I can't think of a way to change that value.

i'm pretty close to bombing it all off for jimp...

Please update your question so that it provides a minimal-repro of your issue; you don't include a Dockerfile if any. How are you running the image locally? From the content of the current question, I'm unable to see any obvious issue although it's curious that you get an error when running on Cloud Run but not locally (suggesting that you're running the image differently). There are differences between local and Cloud Run but, as the question is written, I'm unable to explain why your solution doesn't work.

@DazWilkin that was possibly going to be my next thought (although it would be more effort than i'm willing to spend)  Locally i'm simply running node / npm / express on my Mac.
google cloud CLI is doing the containerization and deployment to cloud run for me. My reading has pointed me to the realization that the container environment is likely not identical to my local environment, so since i can't figure the remote config out perhaps all i'm left with is replicating the remote environment locally.  I believe container is Ubuntu 22

Firstly, a thank you to @DazWilkin for the nudge in the right direction;
for anybody else questioning their sanity (or just a bit new to the serverless /container game like myseld)
The trick here is to write your own dockerfile, rather than relying on Google Cloud CLI to do it all for you. Steps i followed:

run gcloud beta code dev in your directory (Saying yes to installing various services and docker desktop locally) - this'll replicate what's going to happen when you deploy to cloud run allowing you to see locally what's going on - needless to say this is what illuminated the issue locally for me.
create a folder in the root of your application for fonts (and called fonts). for my own purposes i've just dropped an Arial.ttf in mine, you could add whatever truetype fonts you like in that folder
create yourself a Dockerfile in the root of your application, after a bit of trial and error combining information i found from a medium.com article and an example docker file on google cloud github i pulled together the following:


FROM node:20-slim

# copy the /fonts directory into a folder that's visible to fontconfig 
# and install fontconfig service in the container then clear the font cache

COPY --chown=node:node  --chmod=755 /fonts ./usr/local/share/fonts
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y fontconfig
RUN fc-cache -f -v

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]



now run gcloud beta code dev and you should see a working sharp with text instead of boxes :)

